# Dynamics CRM Database Metadata Fields

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to know the purpose of these fields in the Dynamics CRM Metadata tables

- VersionNumber
- SupportingSolutionId
- IntroducedVersion
- {Entity}RowId
- ComponentState
- OverwriteTime
- IsManaged

Also, please describe or provide links about how the Dynamics CRM Metadata Model works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some info about the [Metadata Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309434.aspx)

Here is a breakdown of the different items you [asked about](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546(v=crm.5).aspx)

Hope that helps.

Edit:

- [VersionNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309435.aspx) For internal use only. the version number of
  something
- [IntroducedVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481602(v=crm.6).aspx) A version number that represents the version
  of the solution that the solution component was added in.
- [{Entity}RowId](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/144139.aspx) serves as the key between for example header and
  line records.
- [ComponenetState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546.aspx#bkmk_componentstate) These values represent the possible states of
  solution components.
- [IsManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546.aspx#bkmk_componentstate) - A Boolean option set used for whether a solution
  component is managed.

Could not find an Exact Reference for these two but this is my understand of what they are:

OverwriteTime - OverwriteTime='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'  as a default it changes to the current time when you change something (like a view or delete something)

SupportingSolutionId - it sounds like it's the solution id (or default solution id) for a given solution

Comment: Thanks for your help; but the link contains only the definition of ComponenetState property but the others doesn't exist